# Hide <dt>when divs have display none

Tags: javascript, html, hide, dt

I want when all the divs with class "conteudoGuia" inside `<dt>` are `display: none`, the `<dt>` receive `display: none`

Someone can help and explain me?

I tried much alternatives and not got a answer.

```js
    const searchInput = document.getElementById('searchBox');

    searchInput.addEventListener('input', function () {
      const searchTerm = searchInput.value.trim().toLowerCase();
      const contentElements = document.getElementsByClassName('conteudoGuia');

      for (let i = 0; i < contentElements.length; i++) {
        const titleElement = contentElements[i].querySelector('.tituloGuia');
        const descriptionElement = contentElements[i].querySelector('.descricaoGuia');
        const boldTags = contentElements[i].getElementsByTagName('b');

        let matchFound = false;

        for (let j = 0; j < boldTags.length; j++) {
          const wordInTag = boldTags[j].textContent.trim().toLowerCase();
          if (wordInTag.includes(searchTerm)) {
            matchFound = true;
            break;
          }
        }

        if (matchFound) {
          titleElement.style.display = '';
          descriptionElement.style.display = '';
        } else {
          titleElement.style.display = 'none';
          descriptionElement.style.display = 'none';
        }
      }
    });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hello, World!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <dl class="box">
    <div id="searchDiv" class="searchDiv">
      <input type="text" id="searchBox" name="searchText" class="searchBox" placeholder="Oque você está procurando?" />
      
    </div>

    <dt>TESTE DT 1</dt>
    <dd>
      <div id="autorizacao">
        <div class="conteudoGuia">
          <div class="tituloGuia">
            <p><b>Titulo Primeiro </b></p>
          </div>
          <div class="descricaoGuia">
            <p>
              "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            </p>
            </hr>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </dd>

    <dt>TESTE DT 2</dt>
    <dd>
      <div id="financeiro">
        <div class="conteudoGuia">
          <div class="tituloGuia">
            <p><b>Titulo Segundo </b></p>
          </div>
          <div class="descricaoGuia">
            <p>
              "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            </p>
            </hr>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </dd>
  </dl>
</body>
```

Comment: There are no divs within `dt` in the html you provide.

Comment: @KooiInc 
so to improve the code I need to first reach the <dd> and then the <dt>, correct?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is an error in your code:
`</hr>` should be `<hr>`.

Then the way to do this is to Simply loop through each div inside the dd and check the display property. If all of them have display: none, also hide the dd

```js
const searchInput = document.getElementById('searchBox');

searchInput.addEventListener('input', function() {
  const searchTerm = searchInput.value.trim().toLowerCase();
  const contentElements = document.getElementsByClassName('conteudoGuia');

  for (let i = 0; i < contentElements.length; i++) {
    const titleElement = contentElements[i].querySelector('.tituloGuia');
    const descriptionElement = contentElements[i].querySelector('.descricaoGuia');
    const boldTags = contentElements[i].getElementsByTagName('b');

    let matchFound = false;

    for (let j = 0; j < boldTags.length; j++) {
      const wordInTag = boldTags[j].textContent.trim().toLowerCase();
      if (wordInTag.includes(searchTerm)) {
        matchFound = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (matchFound) {
      titleElement.style.display = '';
      descriptionElement.style.display = '';
    } else {
      titleElement.style.display = 'none';
      descriptionElement.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }

  // Check if all the content elements are hidden, and if so, hide the corresponding <dd>
  const ddElements = document.getElementsByTagName('dd');
  for (let i = 0; i < ddElements.length; i++) {
    const contentElementsInsideDd = ddElements[i].getElementsByTagName('div');
    let allContentHidden = true;

    for (let j = 0; j < contentElementsInsideDd.length; j++) {
      if (contentElementsInsideDd[j].classList.contains('conteudoGuia') &&
        contentElementsInsideDd[j].style.display !== 'none') {
        allContentHidden = false;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (allContentHidden) {
      ddElements[i].style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      ddElements[i].style.display = '';
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<body>
  <dl class="box">
    <div id="searchDiv" class="searchDiv">
      <input type="text" id="searchBox" name="searchText" class="searchBox" placeholder="Oque você está procurando?" />
    </div>

    <dt>TESTE DT 1</dt>
    <dd>
      <div id="autorizacao">
        <div class="conteudoGuia">
          <div class="tituloGuia">
            <p><b>Titulo Primeiro </b></p>
          </div>
          <div class="descricaoGuia">
            <p>
              Some text
            </p>
            <hr>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </dd>

    <dt>TESTE DT 2</dt>
    <dd>
      <div id="financeiro">
        <div class="conteudoGuia">
          <div class="tituloGuia">
            <p><b>Titulo Segundo </b></p>
          </div>
          <div class="descricaoGuia">
            <p>
              Some other text
            </p>
            <hr>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </dd>
  </dl>
</body>
```

Comment: Neither of the `<dt>` elements in the posted HTML have any `<div>` children.

Comment: I don't think this is what I'm looking for.

When word not found or not exists in title inside <dt>, the <dt> hide but back when delete word or the text is empty. Did you think possible with this structure?

Comment: @Bauluccy Perhaps you should try to use a translator to check your English? It is very hard to understand what you mean.
Also, @Pointy made a valid point... There are no div elements inside the `<dt>` ^_^; Changed the code to use `<dd>` instead. If that's not what you want then I wish you good luck.